# How to have multiple archive pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I am building a site that needs pages such as News, Events, Projects and People. My question is, how should I achieve this in WordPress? Do I use custom post types? And if so, how do I have a page for each?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use categories as News, Projects etc. and use category archive page as the archive for them. But this will limit the functionality as you can not **easily** categorize the posts within that category. So I recommend using cusom post type for that.

If you decide to go with custom post type then you'll need to set the `has_archive` parameter to `true` While [registering post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), That will enable archive page for that post type, It uses [`$post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters) as slug for archive page for that custom post type, then archive page url will be
`mysite.com/post_type/`

Comment: That's helpful, distinguishing the use of categories from custom post types - thank you for clearing that up for me. I created a custom post type, with `has_archive` set to true, but going to `/post_type_slug` isn't doing anything.

Comment: does it giving 404 error ?

Comment: No, it takes me to my home page.

Comment: this sort of work but I cannot access to `mysite.com/post_type/2012/02` for examples. Moreover the links of widget archive always point to thinks like `mysite.com/2012/02`...